# filter queryset returned from ManyRelatedManager

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset of model "A" that I'm attempting to do some values/annotate computation on. Model "A" has a ManyToMany relationship with model B. From model "A", I would like to be able to access a filtered subset of "B" models based on a field in "B". How would I change my model "A" to support this sort of pattern?

Dummy example:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
  is_digital = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  readership = models.IntegerField()

class Article(models.Model):
  language = models.CharField()
  published_in = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

# returns a queryset of {publications: total readership} for the articles
$ articles = Articles.objects.filter(language='en')
$ articles.values('published_in').annotate(Sum('readership'))
```

I would like to return a query of publications and total readership for the articles **only for publications that are digital**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation).

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Case, When, IntegerField

Article.objects.annotate(
    total_readership=Sum(
        Case(
            When(published_in__is_digital=True, then=1),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )
)
```